# Getting com.android.volley.ServerError in Volley library Android

Tags: android, android-volley

I would getting data from web. I use Voley. But I get com.android.volley.ServerError error.

Codes:

```
        String url = "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/haberler.php";

        haberler = new ArrayList<String>();

        StringRequest stringrequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>(){
            public void onResponse(String response){

                try {

                    JSONArray haberjson = new JSONArray(response);

                    for(int i = 0; i < haberjson.length(); i++){

                        JSONObject haberobje = haberjson.getJSONObject(i);

                        Toast.makeText(haber.this, haberobje.getString("haber"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        haberler.add(haberobje.getString("haber"));

                    }

                }catch(JSONException jsone1){

                    Toast.makeText(haber.this, jsone1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError ve1){

                Toast.makeText(haber.this, ve1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        stringrequest.setRetryPolicy( new DefaultRetryPolicy(50000, 5, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        RequestQueue requestqueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(haber.this);
        requestqueue.add(stringrequest);
```

Photo:

[print stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6zqG.png)

The codes are right?

How I can resolve this problem?

I need your help.

Comment: Please post the relevant stack trace segment when you need help with an error.

Comment: @Barns I added print stack trace photo link in question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstable try to use error.printStackTrace() to print your stack trace which gives you your actual error. Secondable check if your url is true or if you are messing parameters on your post request.

Comment: I added print stack trace photo link in question.

Comment: do you use emulator ? and what's  ip do you use in your url please ?

Answer (score 0):

**127.0.0.1** is the loopback ip address on your android device. You need the ip address of your computer. I presume you 're running on an emulator or Android device of some sort. If your server is running on a local Wifi network, use the IP address of your Wifi adapter then replace **127.0.0.1** with that address.

TLDR; Use you server's IP address instead of **127.0.0.1**

Linux: **ifconfig [wlan0]**

Windows: **ipconfig**